# MongoDB large amount of writes solutions

Tags: python, mongodb, performance

I'm here as a last resort.
I have two huge collections in the mongoDB and a python script for crawling some data and insert/update data in the db. 
I want to enhance performance as it takes long time for inserting records. 
The rate is something like 50-60 queries per-second now and I'd like to increase it to more like more than 200. 
I have no idea if it is even possible or what I have to do to make it happens.
Also, I have a huge load on the CPU. Right now with this amount of queries the CPU load is 95% (I have to Xeon CPUs in the server, 90GB ram and SSD hard drive)

I have the index and tried to do all the configurations which MongoDB suggested.

Are there any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: `insert,delete,read` is okay but `update` is bad thing(`X2` waste resource). Did you count how many `hash` create on same `DB` ? Another point is your `_id` definitions, you can't create basic `_id` if got a lot load(Additional : do not use  large `DB` size, set `db_names, collection_names` as a `index`).

Comment: On your machine : you got wrong data pattern and access method if got **`>1ms`** access time!
`DB-1 in HDD-1, DB-2 in HDD-2` or `DB-1 in PC-1, DB-2 in PC-2` so sata-3 not have same reflex on work ! What is your `PC-Cache` and `FSB` performance graphics ? Maybe this is not an `MongoDB` issue !

Comment: @dsgdfg can you link me to a reference for _id definitions? What should I use?

Comment: It determines your data structure,these problems occur because you already use non-unique mold. `your data, your computer and your unique pattern` which guide can help you ? Don't search db, only add an entry to `INSERTED-DB` !

Answer (score 0):

You can perform [bulk inserts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite).

Have a look at [this mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/),
It is possible to write a number of records at a time (for example 50) instead of 1 by 1.

For that, adjust your code to perform the write operations **once you have a number of crawled records in memory**, this will accelerate your process.

You can also visit [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) resource for further study on capped collections.

Comment: I forgot to say, I'm using bulk write too. I've tested with different numbers of bulk too. ( from 50 to 1000 ) it looks like that bulk writes also insert one by one. Whatever it is , didn't solve my problem :(

Comment: ops! then another approach to save into mongodb, like collecting your records in faster storage (disk) and another process inserting whatever is new there...

Comment: Thanks, I'm about to forget all about MongoDB and start saving data on files. :)